# alternative of mb_convert_encoding 'HTML-ENTITIES'

Tags: php, domdocument, mb-convert-encoding

I use this code:

```
$wpCharset = "UTF8" //or any other charset
//http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', $wpCharset); 
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', $wpCharset);
$success = $dom->loadHtml('<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=' . $wpCharset . '" /><body>' . $content);
```

The problem is that there are users who do not have a working "mbstring" extension installed on the server. Is there any alternative
of mb_convert_encoding in this case?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

just use `$content = htmlentities($content)`

It is UTF-8 Compatible.
To see all Compatiblities check out php.net : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This just replaces double-quotes in the string which would be OK for XML. If you want to escape single-quotes to,  use `$content = htmlentitites($content,ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: Thank you, but results are not the same: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/daed3482776cce6118c82d27f554b945f126faba

Comment: oh i see. but mbstring is natively built-in in php 4.0.6+, but not activated by default. If you really need this you should add this to your Requirements in the documentation. Why do you even need this? XML suppports utf-8 ?